# How to record a KML tour with absolute altitude mode in Google Earth?

Tags: kml, google-earth

In the [KML developer's guide](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/touring#knownissues) it is written that the Google Earth tour recording mechanism creates FlyTos in *absolute* altitude mode. But when I record a tour in GE free 7.0.2, FlyTos are generated in *relative to sea* altitude mode. And I found no settings that would change that behaviour.

What must I do to really get *absolute* mode tours on recording?

Comment: Can you show the outputted KML? If you switch the altitude mode to absolute there does it fix the issue?